# IdentityServer4 external authentication fails on localhost only due to invalid Identity.External cookie (cannot be configured)

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, identityserver4

I am building a React+Redux SPA with dotnetcore 3.1 and Identity Server 4, attempting to implement external authentication (Github) for sign-in. I have largely followed [the sample application](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers/tree/dev/samples) provided by the Github oauth library. However, I have also tried using Google sign-in (which is not third party) with the same symptoms.

First the user loads `/api/auth/github`:

```
    public IActionResult Oauth([FromRoute] string provider) {
      provider = GetProviderName(provider);
      if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(provider)) {
        return BadRequest();
      }
      AuthenticationProperties properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(
        provider, "/api/auth/callback");
      Log.Information("Properties: {@props}", properties);
      return new ChallengeResult(provider, properties);
    }
```

After logging in, the `/signin-github` endpoint is correctly triggered, which redirects to my `/api/auth/callback` endpoint:

```
    [HttpGet("callback")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Callback() {
      Log.Information("USER: {@user}", User);
      
      ExternalLoginInfo info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
      if (info == null) {
        return Unauthorized("No login info found");
      }
      Log.Information("External: {@external}", info);

      // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login.
      SignInResult result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false, bypassTwoFactor : true);
      return await HandleSigninResult(result);
    }
```

However, the `No login info found` is always triggered. With debug logs on, I can see:

```
AuthenticationScheme: "Identity.External" was not authenticated.
```

I believe the issue has to do with cookies when using `localhost:5000`. I had to set `cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;` on the `CorrelationCookie` before the hand-off would succeed at all. Looking at the headers from the `/signin-github` endpoint, it is attempting to set the `Identity.External` cookie. However, unlike the correlation cookie, this header is unmodified (no `samesite=lax` policy), and I **cannot find any mechanism by which to edit the `Identity.External` cookie**.

I finally ended up deploying the app to production, and indeed the problem went away (because the `SameSite` modification is no longer necessary).

I have already tried to use ConfigureApplicationCookie, which does affect the other cookies in my app, but not the `Identity.External` cookie. Here is  configuration:

```
    private static void ConfigureCookie(string name, CookieBuilder cookie) {
      cookie.Name = name;
      cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
      cookie.SecurePolicy =  CookieSecurePolicy.None;
    }

    public static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration) {
      // Identity Server
      services.AddDefaultIdentity<UserProfile>(options => {
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
        options.Stores.MaxLengthForKeys = 64;
      }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<OWSData>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

      services.AddIdentityServer((options) => {
        options.PublicOrigin = root;
        options.IssuerUri = root;
        options.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = $"{root}/account/login";
        options.UserInteraction.LogoutUrl = $"{root}/account/logout";
        options.UserInteraction.ErrorUrl = $"{root}/account/error";
        options.UserInteraction.ConsentUrl = $"{root}/account/terms-of-service";
        options.UserInteraction.DeviceVerificationUrl = $"{root}/account/device-verification";
      }).AddApiAuthorization<UserProfile, OWSData>(options => {
        // Serilog.Log.Information("Clients: {@clients}", options.Clients);
      });
      services.AddScoped<ICurrentUser, CurrentUser>();
      services.AddTransient<IReturnUrlParser, AuthReturnUrl>();

      // Auth (JWT)
      services.AddAuthentication(options => {
                 options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
               })
              .AddCookie((options) => {
                 ConfigureCookie(".OWS.Core.", options.Cookie, webHost);

                 options.LoginPath = "/account/login";
                 options.AccessDeniedPath = "/account/denied";
                 options.LogoutPath = "/account/logout";
                 options.SlidingExpiration = true;
               })
              .AddIdentityServerJwt()
              .AddGoogle(options => {
                 options.ClientId = configuration["Google:ClientId"];
                 options.ClientSecret = configuration["Google:ClientSecret"];

                 ConfigureCookie(".OWS.Correlation.", options.CorrelationCookie);
               })
              .AddGitHub(options => {
                 options.Scope.Add("user:email");
                 options.EnterpriseDomain = configuration["GitHub:EnterpriseDomain"];

                 options.ClientId = configuration["GitHub:ClientId"];
                 options.ClientSecret = configuration["GitHub:ClientSecret"];

                 ConfigureCookie(".OWS.Correlation.", options.CorrelationCookie);
               });

      // Auth (Password)
      services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options => {
        //Password settings
        options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
        options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
        options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
        options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;

        //Lockout settings
        options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
        options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

        //User settings
        options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
          "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@";
        options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
      });

      // Cookies
      services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => {
        ConfigureCookie(".OWS.Core.", options.Cookie, webHost);
      });
```

Comment: Try SameSiteMode.None?

Comment: @ToreNestenius Would that I could! The problem is that I have no hook to edit the `Identity.External` cookie!